# How can we implement 'adaptive cards' in angular js 1.x

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

I would like to implement visualizer in my angular ui for Bot.Can anyone help how can we render adaptive cards in an angular ui. I am using Angular 1.x.

Comment: I am unable to add the custome onExecuteAction to the directive. Please guide me. https://plnkr.co/edit/2YB2zV3FL4JZgJ2yC4FG?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You can render Adaptive Cards in a client-side web application using the HTML client library [`microsoft-adaptivecards`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/microsoft-adaptivecards) available via NPM.

For instructions and a code example, check out: http://adaptivecards.io/documentation/#display-libraries-htmlclient

There are also code samples available on the Adaptive Cards GitHub repository:
https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards/tree/master/samples

Comment: Hi Nills, I am unable to capture the onExecuteAction emitted by the Adaptive Card. Can you please provide any pointers on the missing piece here.Attaching the plnkr code https://plnkr.co/edit/2YB2zV3FL4JZgJ2yC4FG

Comment: Please ask a new question and I will answer it there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44892036/unable-to-capture-adaptive-card-events-triggered-in-angular-js-1-x-directive   Hi nills please find the link