# Unable to capture Adaptive Card events triggered in angular js 1.x directive

Tags: node.js, botframework, direct-line-botframework, adaptive-cards

I am unable to capture the onExecuteAction emitted by the Adaptive Card. Can you please provide any pointers on the missing piece here.Also I am facing similar issue in binding,trigger and capturing events from the Adaptive Cards like showing/collapsing elements(triggered by Action.Showcard elements). Any pointers/guidence is appreciated.Thanks in advance.Attaching the plnkr code.
https://plnkr.co/edit/2YB2zV3FL4JZgJ2yC4FG      `

```
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        scope:false,
        template: renderedCardNew.outerHTML,//$scope.trustedHtml,//'<p style="background-color:{{color}}">Hello World</p>',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.bind('click', function () {

                scope.$apply(function () {
                    scope.color = "white";
                });`.
```

Comment: Are you using .NET or Node SDK for BotBuilder? What channel are you using to display the cards? Aka - Skype? WebChat? MS Teams? Emulator? Slack?

Comment: @NilsW based on the code provided I don't think the botframework tag is relevant here

Comment: Hi Nils, We use directline channel. We built a custom webchat on Angular 1 stack. Would like to implement adaptive cards as an directive  use it in our webchat.